# Consulta Group By con Order By no funcionan juntos

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select * from tblreviews WHERE Estado=1 group by Website ORDER BY fchFecha DESC limit 5
```

En la cual solo me funciona la parte del `group by` pero no me ordena el resultado en la fecha mas reciente.

Gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: puedes mostrarnos una imagen de la tabla y datos? o del error...

Comment: Coloca tu tabla con un ejemplo de los datos por favor

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tblreviews AS t
WHERE t.Estado = 1
  AND t.id = (SELECT tt.id FROM tblreviews AS tt WHERE tt.Website=t.Website ORDER BY tt.fchFecha DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY t.Website
LIMIT 5
```

Buscamos, para cada `Website` con `Estado = 1`, **solo** el que coincida con el registro de mayor fecha (por eso usamos orden descendente).
Ojo: Es imprescindible el `LIMIT 1`en la subconsulta, de lo contrario obtendremos un error o resultados imprevistos.

Hay que aclarar que esta consulta no tiene en cuenta el valor de `Estado` en la fecha  usada para la ordenación, para eso la consulta debería ser:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tblreviews AS t
WHERE t.Estado = 1
 AND t.id = (SELECT tt.id FROM tblreviews AS tt WHERE tt.Website=t.Website AND t.Estado = 1 ORDER BY tt.fchFecha DESC LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY t.Website
LIMIT 5
```

Así solo se tendría en cuenta, tanto para mostrar como para establecer que fecha usar, las `tblreviews` con `Estado = 1`, la diferencia es sutil pero influirá en el resultado.

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, lo debes hacer con una subconsulta:

```
 SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT * FROM tblreviews WHERE Estado=1 ORDER BY fchFecha DESC) T
 GROUP BY T.Website LIMIT 5
```

De esta forma ordenas el resultado condicionado, y luego lo agrupas.

**tabla:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte,la consulta que me sugeriste esta bien  pero aun así no me arrojan los ultimos datos insertados, cuando realizo un order by por fchFecha si lo hace

Comment: No entendí entonces tu requerimiento, puedes aclarar mi error? edite mi respuesta mostrando el resultado, en base a eso podrías aclarar tu solicitud? Ademas que con tu `limit` estas solo mostrando los primero 5 registros...

Comment: previamente realice un order by de fchFecha para ver los datos mas recientes de la tabla, esos datos debo ordenarlos por ese campo website. La consulta funciona pero los datos que muestra no son los mas recientes

Comment: podrías subir un ejemplo de tu tabla o de lo que quieres ver? porque realmente te entiendo como muestro los resultados, necesito entenderte con un ejemplo....

Comment: El Query que subí, te mostrara el ultimo `website` creado(fecha mas reciente) que tenga `estado = 1` eso es lo que buscas?

Comment: faltaría un segundo order by para ordenar el grupo

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo con la funcion `MAX` asi:

```
select * from tblreviews WHERE Estado=1 group by Website 
ORDER BY MAX(fchFecha) DESC limit 5
```

Comment: gracias por el aporte pero aun así no me arrojan los ultimos datos insertados, cuando realizo un order by por fchFecha si lo hace